# Can't get a response from my server. Why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I can't get a response from my server. I am using postman and running the following post request:

```
localhost:4000/users/register?email=test@gmail.com&f_name=testf&s_name=tests&password=test
```

It hangs for a very long time and then says:

```
Could not get any response
```

This is my code:

```
[user.route.js]
const express = require('express');
const userRoutes = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

//require User model in the routes module
let User = require('../models/user.model.js');

//Make router use cors to avoid cross origin errors
userRoutes.use(cors);

//secret
process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret';

//define register route
userRoutes.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const today = new Date();
  const userData = {
    email: req.body.email,
    f_name: req.body.f_name,
    s_name: req.body.s_name,
    password: req.body.password,
    created: today
  }
  //Find one user based on email, hash their password and then create a document in the collection for that user
  User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email
    })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          user.password = hash;
          User.create(userData)
            .then(user => {
              res.json({
                status: user.email + ' registered'
              });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.send('error: ' + err);
            });
        });
      }
    });
});

userRoutes.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email
    })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          const payload = {
            _id: user._id,
            f_name: user.f_name,
            s_name: user.s_name,
            email: user.email
          }
          let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: 1440
          });
          res.send(token);
        } else {
          res.json({
            'Error': 'Password Incorrect'
          });
        }
      } else {
        res.json({
          'Error': 'User does not exist'
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});

module.exports = userRoutes;

[user.model.js]
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let User = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  f_name: {
    type: String
  },
  s_name: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  created: {
    type: String
  }
}, {
  collection: 'users'
});

[server.js]
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const PORT = 4000;
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./db.js');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.DB, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(
  () => {
    console.log('Database is connected')
  },
  err => {
    console.log('Can not connect to the database' + err)
  }
);

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var Users = require('./routes/user.route');

//make /users use routes
app.use('/users', Users);

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server is running on Port:', PORT);
});

[db.js]
module.exports = {
  DB: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/pharaohcrud'
}
```

I'm using Node, MongoDB, Mongoose, Vue, Express.

I'm new to Node in general so it's hard for me to give details on what i've done. Please feel free to ask any questions that you need answered to help me with issue and ill answer as thoroughly as i can :)

EDITS:

Here is the updated db.js file

```
module.exports = {
  DB: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/pharaoh'
}
```

Here is the updated post request that im sending to the server through postman:

```
localhost:4000/users/register

[raw json request]
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "f_name": "test",
    "s_name": "test",
    "password": "test"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the user test@gmail.com has not been created?
Because if you find a user `if (!user) {` you never send a response (`res.send('user already existing');`)

Comment: @Adam Cole you're sending your request as query parameter. but in your 'register' route, you're reading from `req.body`. change that to `req.param` or send you request body as `json` in postman

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar ok so i went back and changed my request to x-www-form-urlencoded and entered all the keys and values in, that didn't work :/ do i have to specify which database im using in the code? I guess i would have to but i cant work out where that would go.

Comment: in your register route, you could console.log(req.body) to see if you're getting the correct values. Also you could do `app.use((req, res, next) => console.log(req.url); next())` to see if requests are actually coming through

Comment: That code gave me a syntax error :/ @naga-elixir-jar but console logging the req.body didn't give me anything when i requested again so it must not be able to connect in the first place

Comment: Id like to add that i changed db.js to be 'pharaoh' instead of 'pharaohcrud' as i didn't realise that is supposed to be the name of the database, that didn't solve it.

Comment: @AdamCole please update your code so we can see the updated code

Comment: @pariola Added the edit

Comment: @AdamCole seems you're only handling when the user doesn't exist. Kindly check with another test email

Comment: @pariola test@gmail.com doesn't exist, im trying to use a post request to add test@gmail.com to the database, then i can try to get the login function working which checks that the user is in the database.

Comment: I would advise you add logs to the step by step processes so you can better identify where it's breaking

Answer (score 0):

You have to send json data with your post request not query strings.

In postman, select "Body" tab and choose "raw" and from the dropdown menu select "json" format. Send your user data as Json,  this will solve the issue.

[Image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNYFw.png)

Comment: try to console.log("Hello") at the top in your register post route and see if it is printing in the console when you make a request.

Comment: Nothing was logged. It just says 'loading' for a very long time on Postman and then says it can't connect. Am i supposed to add a route for /users somewhere or is that done when i say `app.use('/users', Users)`?

Comment: Seems that it is not able to connect to the route.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hcnxayU That is what the response window looks like when it fails

Comment: You are requesting to localhost:5000 but in server.js you have used port=4000, that is why you are getting an error..

Answer (score 0):

I went deleted all database-related code and retyped it, and now it works. I guess the lesson here is to always pay attention while typing code to make sure you're writing it correctly.